# wordpress keeps redirecting to deleted page

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks, slug

I have a WordPress theme which contains multiple pages one is a contact page, I didn't like this contact page so created another page so the old page

The problem:

What do I need to do solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the permalinks for the specified page.

For that , Go to the pages section and select your desired page from wordpress admin dashboard
Now in the right side, click on permalinks option and update your slug in the url-slug box 
Hopefully , That'd resolve your proble